# Compare ID columns and update Dates if changed

Tags: javascript, arrays, datetime, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have 2 sheets viz., `Sht1` & `Sht2`. I am looping through the `ID column in Sht1` and trying to match it with `ID column in Sht2`. `If there is a match`, then `check if the Date in Sht2 is different than the Date in Sht1`. If it is, then `update the Date in Sht1 with this new Date`.

**Sht1:**

[image: Sht1]

**Sht2:**

[image: Sht2]

for e.g.:
From the above screenshots, the `Sht1` matching ID's in `Sht2` are `10001,10003,10006,10010,10011`.
Of these, only `10001,10006,10011` have new Dates. So only for these ID's, these new Dates should get copied to `Sht1`.

As the Data is large, looping through the ID columns, matching them and then checking if the dates are different and finally updating new dates back to Sht1, is taking a lot of time. Is there an eloquent way to do this without looping and reading/writing to sheet - like picking up the Data in the 2 Sheets as JSON Objects viz., `ObjSht1 & ObjSht2`, updating the Dates for the matching ID's in `ObjSht1`, then transferring this JSON Object `ObjSht1` to `Sht1` in one go?

**Edit:**
@TheMaster the modified script is :

```
function myFunction() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const sht1 = ss.getSheetByName("Sht1");
  const sht2 = ss.getSheetByName("Sht2");
  const idMap = sht2.getDataRange().getValues().reduce( (mp,[,id,,date]) => mp.set(id, date), new Map );
   console.log(idMap);


const rg1 = sht1.getDataRange();
const values1 = rg1.getValues();
values1.forEach(row => row[2] = idMap.get(row[0]));
rg1.setValues(values1);
}
```

@TheMaster, This time it replaces the dates in Sht1 with the dates from Sht2 where the ID's match. But it also wipes out the other dates from Sht1 where the ID's do not match.
Also, I think the code is not comparing if dates have changed, but just dumping the dates from Sht2 to Sht1.

See updated Screenshots:

[image: updated Sht1]

Comment: For starters, you can use indexOf to match particular value with a list. I would also use a for loop because I am not sure if there is a quicker way, since the matches won't be sequential, thus you can't update a range of cells at once.

Comment: Show your attempt at executing *picking up the Data in the 2 Sheets as JSON Objects viz., ObjSht1 & ObjSht2, updating the Dates for the matching ID's in ObjSht1, then transferring this JSON Object ObjSht1 to Sht1 in one go*

Comment: @TheMaster that was just an idea from a recent post. I don't know how to do it.

Comment: Try and show. When else are you going to try it?

Comment: As I said, don't know how to do it. It was just an idea. Any better way to do it?

Comment: Read and practice the links provided below until you get it.

Comment: What Google Apps Script runtime is your script using?

Comment: Apps script engine is V8

Comment: What is `row[2]`?

Comment: not sure i understood the code...isn't row[2] the Date column of Sht1 to be replaced by the changed Dates from Sht2, where ID in Sht1 matches the ID in Sht2?

Comment: You just need to add back the date using or `||`. Edited my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Create a [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) of {id => date} of  the  second sheet using [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce)
- Modify the  first sheet values in place using [forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)

#### Sample script:

```
function datesFromSht2ToSht1() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const sht1 = ss.getSheetByName("Sht1");
  const sht2 = ss.getSheetByName("Sht2");
  const idMap = sht2.getDataRange().getValues().reduce( (mp,[,id,,date]) => mp.set(id, date), new Map );
  const rg1 = sht1.getDataRange();
  const values1 = rg1.getValues();
  values1.forEach(row => row[2] = idMap.get(row[0]) || row[2]);
  rg1.setValues(values1);
}
```

Comment: actually it is doing the opposite i.e. updating the dates in Sht2 instead of Sht1. How do i swap the Sheets?

Comment: @sifar change all `sht2` to `sht1` and vice versa and adjust the columns  positions accordingly?

Comment: tried that...not working...i guess you are setting positions in reduce `reduce((mp,[id,,date])` ....... `values2.forEach(row => row[3] = idMap.get(row[1]));` errors on these lines...

Comment: @sifar That is right. Set positions properly. Show your  modified script and quote the error, if you're still unable to figure out after reasonable effort.

Comment: works! brillant and very consice code. Thanks a bunch!

Comment: @sifar Make sure to understand  and practice regularly.